# Is there a way to verify the content being passed in Observer.next function in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, api, frontend

I have been trying to create a front end Chat Application using Socket.IO-Client.

Below is the service event function that checks if the user is either online or offline:

```js
verifyUser = () => {
  return Observable.create((observer) => {
    this.socket.on("verifyUser", (data) => {
      observer.next(data);
    });
  });
}
```

Below is the component that triggers the `VerifyUser` event:

```js
public verifyUserConfirmation: any = () => {
  this.socketService.verifyUser().subscribe((data) => {
    this.disconnectedSocket = false;
    this.socketService.setUser(this.authToken);
  });
}
```

I am assuming that the data is not being handled properly as the HTML code below doesn't render:

```html
<a class="navbar-brand text-white">
  {{userInfo.firstName}} {{userInfo.lastName}}
  <i class="online" *ngIf="disconnectedSocket == false"></i>
  <i class="offline" *ngIf="disconnectedSocket == true"></i>
</a>
```

Is there a way to verify if the data is being passed in the observable correctly?

Comment: this.socketService.verifyUser().subscribe((data)=>{
console.log(data);
});
This way you can have a look what data is emitted from backend server

Comment: Unfortunately, no statements is being printed there. I tried to console log "Hi", that too is not displayed.

Comment: is there a event named verifyUser emitted, which you are try to listen to and is your socket connection established?

Comment: Yes there is as mentioned in the code above.

However, I just noticed that the socket connection was not established because of wrong URL.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: Yes it does. API documentation was incorrect, so event name had to be changed.
Thanks for your help.